# getting syntax parse to work with custom operators

Tags: racket

I have my own versions of `+` `-` etc and am wondering if there is a way to make the following code work?

```
(syntax-parse #'(+ 1 2)
  [(op e1 e2) #'(my-op e1 e2)])
```

I imagine one "long" way of doing this would be:

```
(syntax-parse #'(+ 1 2)
  [(op e1 e2) #:when (equal? op '+) #'(my-+ e1 e2)]
  ...)
```

Comment: It is unclear to me why you are doing this, and I wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188673). *Why* do you have your own versions of `+` and `-`? Why do you need to look at existing expressions to find uses of Racket’s `+` and `-` to replace them with your own? Could you rebind `+` and `-` locally and let lexical scope do the rest for you?

Comment: To expand on what @AlexisKing said, in `#lang racket`, `+` and `-` are just functions. If you want to make new versions of `+` and `-`—maybe you want to make them work on strings as well as numbers—you would normally just implement your operations as functions and perhaps call them `+` and `-` with `rename-out`. But if you're doing something more unusual, there are other techniques that might help: checking for symbolic equality is unlikely to be what you want.